# Combine Class with Database first model

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got an older ASP project that is being re-written into a responsive MVC4 w/bootstrap web application. The original version used direct SQL queries to interact with the application backend SQL database, and a custom class called EmployeeUserInfo that directly queries the ERP system for current employee information(current tasks, hours worked, etc). That connection is strictly read-only.

Using Entity Framework, it was extremely easy to create the models for the various writable databases that make up the application, but how can I add the original EmployeeUserInfo class to this EDMX model? I'd prefer not to rewrite the class because it does a lot of querying and analyzing to build the EmployeeUserInfo object. Is it possible to combine another class with an EF database-first generated model?

I'm stuck now because I can use the EmployeeUserInfo as the model for a view, but then I cannot access the EF generated model to read/write to the application database. I feel like I'm overlooking something here and making this more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: An Edmx file is just a glorified T4 (text template) file, which generates classes for you. You can't add your own code directly to it. You can, however, extend the auto-made classes because they are all `partial` classes.

Comment: If you use EF code first it will be possible to use your EmployeeUserInfo class.

Comment: For now, it was easiest to simply pass this class into the _layout template via the viewbag, and load the other models as needed. The class needs to be constantly refreshed anyway to stay current, and that seemed to be the easiest route to take.